# Redux - initializing the state with async dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have an app which provides me with user details on requesting the static files (so at the very beginning - I don't have to login). I try to initialize the state with async action checking if the user has rights to see the app. But my Auth component, which has the App as a child doesn't re-render on changed props.
The store:

```html
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

store.dispatch(fetchUser());

export default store;
```

In the store, on initialization I dispatch an async action.

The action:

```html
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get('/api/user/information');

  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: response.data
  });
};
```

The action is then passed to the reducer:

The reducer:

```html
export const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
  }
  return state;
};
```

The data from the reducer is then passed to the Auth component.

The Auth component:

```html
class Auth extends Component {
  public render() {
    return this.props.user ? this.props.children : <p>Access denied</p>;
  }
}

export default compose(Connectable)(Auth);
```

The props are passed from the connectablr hoc.

And connectable hoc:

```html
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export const Connectable = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
);
```

So the app just stays on the "Access denied" because the user object is empty. Even more so - when the data is fetched the 'user' prop has another nested 'user' object and then there is data. I want to check if the user is not empty (and fix the double user nested object). But I have no idea why the changed props don't re-render the auth app. What can be the reason? Is it not possible to do async action when initializing the state?

Comment: Is the `rootReducer` combine the `userReducer`?

Comment: No, it combines userReducer as user so that's why the double-nesting.

Comment: I don't think you need `Connectable`, it is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `state.user` to `state.userReducer.user`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.userReducer.user
});
```

---

Your reducers design can be better.

https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

```
export const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
  }
  return state;
};
```

---

if you want init user, I get you a example.

```
import * as actions from '../../actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user
});

export const Connectable = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
);
```

and

```
class Auth extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
     this.props.fetchUser()
 }
 render() {
    return this.props.user ? this.props.children : <p>Access denied</p>;
  }
}

export default compose(Connectable)(Auth);
```

Comment: What problem is that?

Comment: you can see this, https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: I'm not sure why it has problems. I'm not mutating state. Can you be more specific?

Comment: your state tree is big. like userReducer, if your user payload need some process will difficult.

Comment: Question: why I cannot do it when initializing the state? Why it needs to be done in the componentDidMount method of the Auth component?

Comment: that is two big question involves a lot thing. why I cannot do it when initializing the state? you just createStore, No one knows him, until `ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} />,  element)`

Comment: Why it needs to be done in the componentDidMount method of the Auth component? This involves the life cycle of the component. Not necessarily in Auth component.